# How can I handle validation of non-latin script input in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I am trying to adapt a php application to handle non-latin scripts (specifically: Japanese, simplified Chinese and Arabic).  The app's data validation routines make frequent use of regular expressions to check input, but I am not sure how to adapt the \w character type to other languages without installing additional locales on the system (which I cannot rely on).

Previous developers to have worked on the app have simply added needed characters to the regexes as the number of languages we supported grew (you frequently see "[\wÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉ... etc" in the code), but I can't really do this for all the alphabets I need to support now.

Does anybody out there have some advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: What does "validation" mean? You could use the locale-aware [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php), but what you're asking for is "what is an alphanumeric character _in any locale_"...

Comment: unicode is broken in PHP, I know that much. It would be nice to see links to some libraries that people know to work.

Comment: @Ярослав How is Unicode "broken" in PHP? Most basic string functions don't explicitly support it, that's all. The ones that do work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this comment on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php#102756

for example:

```
//$string may only contain arabic letters
preg_match('@^\p{Arabic}+$@u',$string);

//$string may only contain cyrillic letters
preg_match('@^\p{Cyrillic}+$@u',$string);

//$string may contain word-characters and greek
preg_match('@^[\p{Greek}\w]+$@u',$str);
```

...and so on

demonstration: http://cecb.freephptest.com/

Comment: All fine and well, but is there anything that matches "any alphabetical character in any language or script"?

Comment: Ah, according to [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) some languages support `\p{Letter}` to match "any sort of letter". Does PHP?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: PHP supports it (if PCRE engine is compiled with Unicode support - most are) but you still have to use the `u` modifier.

Comment: Thank you.  This works, and your help is greatly appreciated. For those who are wondering, the regex is /\p{L}/u (the "u") modifier enabling unicode support.